# tensorflow 2.6.0 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'random generator'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I recently installed last version of tensorflow and also updated keras, but when I try to define a layer I have the following error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
input = tf.keras.layers.Input((299,299,3))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(input)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jose_Marquez\.conda\envs\jose37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 530, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jose_Marquez\.conda\envs\jose37\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dropout.py", line 96, in __init__
    self._random_generator = backend.RandomGenerator(seed)
AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'RandomGenerator'
```

It was working prior to the TF upgrade but I updated everything I thought could be wrong (cuda v11.4, cudnn V8.2.4)

It is inidependant to the input, have the problem from the definition itself

```
import tensorflow as tf
x_s = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-48b69409a9ba> in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 x_s = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)

c:\users\jose_marquez\.conda\envs\jose37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    529     try:
--> 530       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    531     finally:
    532       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

c:\users\jose_marquez\.conda\envs\jose37\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dropout.py in __init__(self, rate, noise_shape, seed, **kwargs)
     94     self.seed = seed
     95     self.supports_masking = True
---> 96     self._random_generator = backend.RandomGenerator(seed)
     97 
     98   def build(self, input_shape):

AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'RandomGenerator'
```

Comment: Show us the full code. How did you define input?

Comment: Basically doesn't work even with just the definition, that's why I think its related with definition itself

Comment: I just tried your code on Google Colab it worked fine on google colab. Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: It seems that was just a compatibily problem wit TensorFlow and other libraries, I basically erase any TF2 related and reinstalled ans solved the issue. Thanks for the interest

Answer (score 0):

Just erase any Tensorflow realted library and reinstall everything from scratch